# Cloudify Manager: how to associate FloatingIp On Bootstrap

Tags: cloudify

I'm using Cloudify 2.7 with OpenStack Icehouse.

I would like to bootstrap the Cloudify Manager attached to an existing private network, and I would provide a Public Floating IP only to the Cloudify Manager on bootstrap, so that the Cloudify Shell can ssh into the Cloudify Manager.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The particular combination you asking for is not possible with the openstack cloud driver that is packaged with Cloudify. You can see the possible networking options here:
http://getcloudify.org/guide/2.7/clouddrivers/network.html

For what you are asking for, you will need to create a custom cloud driver that uses an existing network (referred to as static network bootstrapping) and then allocate a floating IP to the manager.

This should be a fairly straight-forward change in the cloud driver's startManagementMachines() method (https://github.com/CloudifySource/cloudify/blob/master/esc/src/main/java/org/cloudifysource/esc/driver/provisioning/openstack/OpenStackCloudifyDriver.java#L440)

Please note that Cloudify 2.X has reached End-of-Life and is not supported. You should check out Cloudify 3.2